# how to while true in thread for qgis plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am currently working on qgis plugin that searches for information every 5 seconds from database and refreshes the map. In my first version, I used Qtimer to do this job. However, in my second version I am thinking of using Qthread.

The example code is below:

```
Class worker(QObject):
 def __init__(self,iface,....)
  QObject.__init__(self)
  self.iface=iface
  ...
 def run(self):
  while 1:
  -search informations from DB
  -edit the layers
  -refresh the map
   time.sleep(5)

in the run function of the plugin:
self.thread=QThread()
self.test=worker(self.iface,....) #all the other parameters
self.test.moveToThread(self.thread)
self.thread.started.connect(self.test.run)
self.thread.start()
```

However, when I print something by the created thread, after exactly 16 to 18 iterations, the threads created don't stop working but my CPU at 100% and the main window of qgis freezes or does not work at all.

Can someone explain why this error is happening?

Comment: Please update the question with OS version and anything else that might be relevant to how the threading works under the hood.

Comment: thank you John Barça for your inswer. I'm currently using windows 7 and QGIS 2.10.1 my computer is quadcore with 8 Gb memory. I enabled multithreading on QGIS.

Comment: Please use comments.